# HttpWebRequest doesn't send the + (plus) char

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send a base64 encoded data using a POST request and it contains the "+" char. When I send the request, the "+" is replaced with " " (space). Here goes the code

```
    public string POST(string url, string query)
    {
        HttpWebRequest hwrq = CreateRequest(url);
        hwrq.CookieContainer = Cookies;
        hwrq.Method = "POST";
        hwrq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(query);
        hwrq.ContentLength = data.Length;
        hwrq.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        using (HttpWebResponse hwrs = (HttpWebResponse)hwrq.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(hwrs.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            }
        }
    }

    public HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        Request.UserAgent = UserAgent;
        Request.Accept = Accept;
        Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", AcceptLang);
        Request.AutomaticDecompression = DMethod;
        return Request;
    }
```

I've been tracking the "query" variable, it stays with the "+" char, but when I see the request in sniffer (Charles), the request is sent without the "+".
For example I'm trying to send

> <...>zxJ+zZq<...>

and

> <...>zxJ zZq<...>

is actually sent.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`+` represents space in a query string. It looks like like your `query` variable that you are sending is not properly URL encoded. Unfortunately you haven't shown how you are constructing this `query` string variable but here's the correct way in order to ensure that all values are properly URL encoded:

```
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
values["foo"] = "some + value";
values["bar"] = "some other value";
string query = values.ToString();
// query will equal foo=some+%2b+value&bar=some+other+value
```

Notice how the `+` sign that was originally part of the value is encoded to `%2B`.

If you write the following:

```
string query = "foo=some + value&bar=some other value";
```

I think you see the problem for yourself and the difference between the correct query string which is `foo=some+%2b+value&bar=some+other+value`.

Now this being said here's what I would suggest you in order to improve your code. You could extend the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class so that it can handle cookies, like this:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer Cookies { get; private set; }
    public WebClientEx()
    {
        Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
        return request;
    }
}
```

and now simply:

```
using (var client = new WebClientEx())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-us,en;q=0.5";
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "foo", "some value" },
        { "bar", "some & other + value =" },
    };
    byte[] buffer = client.UploadValues("http://www.example.com", values);
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}
```

See how much easier this is instead of messing around with all those HttpWebRequests, responses, streams, encodings, etc...?

Comment: Worked for WPF 4.5 application like a charm.

Comment: Thank Alot It Works, and I got the value like this : $_POST['foo'];

Answer (score 1):

The form data is sent URL encoded, and a space is encoded into a +, so a + will be decoded into a space.

Use the Server.UrlEncode method to encode the data that you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different content type:

```
hwrq.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

In your example you post raw base64 data (plain text), but you tell the remote server that you are posting a url encoded query string (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). That´s why the remote server tries to url decode your base64 data, which in turn will replace + with space.